# How to get CascadeDeleted entities in change tracker

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Since EF Core 3 the [delete-behaviour changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#cascade). I want to implement soft delete, and I thought this might be helpful...

I have lazy loading enabled and a generic delete method:

```
this.context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
```

Before `SaveChanges` I add meta information.

First I try to find all `ChangeTracker` entries like this:

```
var entityEntries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is IMyMetaDataBase
                        && (x.State == EntityState.Added 
                               || x.State == EntityState.Modified 
                               || x.State == EntityState.Deleted));
```

But I only find the principal entity in above collection to perform soft delete like this:

```
if (entityEntry.Entity is IMyDeletableInterface deletable && entityEntry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
{
    EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    deletable.Deleted = true;
}
```

If I set the `EntityState` modified (which is the thing to do I suppose) the principal entity is set deleted, but all dependent entities remain unchanged. If I don´t change the `EntityState`, all dependent entities will be removed.
My main question: Is there a way to find the entities, EF will remove in cascade operation..?

netcoreapp3.1, ef core 3.1.8

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would help.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    // Soft-Delete 
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted && e.Metadata.GetProperties()
        .Any(x => x.Name == "IsDeleted"))
        .ToList();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        entity.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        entity.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I was not really clear with my question. I´ve updated my question, hope I clarified the scope..